# How to match attributes JSON object values to using Android or Java?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I'm creating a sample using the concepts JSONArray parse to get particular values to match the attributes.

For example:

*sample_struct.json*  file data

```
 [ {
 "query": "Pizza",
 "locations": [94043,90210]
 "mDK": "kk"

       }, {
 "query": "Pizza",
 "locations": [94043,90210]
       }, {
 "query": "akkk",
 "locations": [94043,90210]
       }, {
 "query": "Pizza",
 "locations": [94043,90210], 
 "mDK": "kk"
       }, {
 "query": "Pizza",
 "locations": [94043,90210],"mDK": "ff"
       }, {
 "query": "Pigg",
 "locations": [94043,90210],"mDK": "kk"
       }, {
 "query": "Pgg",
 "locations": [94043,90210],"mDK": "ff"  }, {
 "query": "Pgg",
 "locations": [94043,90210],"mDK": "ff"  }, {
 "query": "Pgg",
 "locations": [94043,90210],"mDK": "ff"  }, {
 "query": "Pgg",
 "locations": [94043,90210],"mDK": "kk"  }]
```

My need is to get "mDk" where the string "kk" to listout within both query and location value also to display it.

```
String mmm = "kk";

JSONArray jsonArray=getJSonData("sample_struct.json");
parseData(jsonArray);

private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        Mo mo = new Mo();
        JSONObject json = null;

        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);

            if(json.get("mDK").equals(mm)) {

                mo.setquery(json.getString("query"));
                mo.setlocations(json.getString("locations));
                mo.setmDK(json.getString("mDk"));
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Without displaying the null values.

Comment: my sample_struct.json file have not a valid json Data.  Check here http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ just copy paste text from file..

Comment: What's the result you're getting now and how does it differ from what you intend to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all its not a valid **JSON**, To make it valid add **Comma** (**,**) at line 3 like here

```
"locations": [94043,90210],
```

Then only you can check like this

```
json = array.getJSONObject(i);

if(json.getString("mDK").equals(mm)){
  //Your logic
}
```

**Remember :** It's not `json.get`, It's `json.getString`

Answer (score 0):

Sample data is wrong.

You are missing a comma

changr

```
     [ {
 "query": "Pizza",
 "locations": [94043,90210]
 "mDK": "kk"
```

to

```
     [ {
 "query": "Pizza",
 "locations": [94043,90210],
 "mDK": "kk"
```